# Is it possible to change react props

Tags: reactjs, react-props

if props are immutable then how can we change it in child component.Is it done by lifecycle method componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState).

Comment: you want to directly change props value in other component?

Comment: yes,is that possible in child components

Comment: A component is not allowed to change it's own props directly. Props come from parent components, and so the parent is responsible for changing those values (which usually come from state within the parent). What do you mean by "other component"?

Comment: @Gopika, I think you can manage the state in your child component where you are receiving the props.. But if you provide more context of what you are trying to achieve then that would be good..

Comment: @Gopika, yes you can change props value in child component as but it is not a best practise. But if you need i can tell you.

Comment: if the prop is passed from a parent component,then can change the props in child component. Because i saw in some docs that a method componentWillReceiveProps(prevProps,nextProps) which compares the values of props

Comment: @ShivanshuGupta yes, can you provide an example to make it clear

Comment: Check out the documentation. `componentWillReceiveProps` deprecated for new versions of React. Anyway it was not intended for changing props. I could recalculate internal state values based on it  but not change the props

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this object is coming as a prop in your child component

```
const user = {
  name: "Abc",
  age: 12,
  gender: "Male",
}
```

If you just want to use props in child component without changing props value then you can simply maintain state in child component or directly use props value if you do not want to maintain state.
With State

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if(this.state.user !== this.props.user) {
    this.setState({ user: this.props.user })
  }
}
```

and if you want to change user values coming from props then you can do like this:

```
const { name, age } = this.props.user;
name = "ABC";
age = 14;
```

Because both props and `const { name, age }` are pointing to same reference only, so it will update props value.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to just change the props value on its own component. You can just create a function on the parent component:

```
updateProps(newValue){
   this.setState({myState: newValue})
}
```

Then you just simply pass the function together with the state as a props:

```
<Child updateProps={this.updateProps} myProps={this.state.myState} />
```

And call the function on your child component:

```
this.props.updateProps('hello')
```